find the largest sub matrix
the larget sub matrix with odd size
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[np.nan, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, np.nan]])


the expected output is

    [[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
    [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, ],
    [255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255],
    [255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255],
    [255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255],
    [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255],
    [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
    [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
    [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
    [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255],
    [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]]



m, n = array.shape

# Initialize the maximum submatrix size and its starting indices
max_submatrix_size = 0
max_submatrix_start_i = 0
max_submatrix_start_j = 0

# Iterate over all possible starting indices of the window
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        # Initialize the window size
        window_size = 0
        # Expand the window until it reaches the end of the array or encounters a non-255 value
        while i + window_size < m and j + window_size < n and array[i + window_size, j + window_size] == 255:
            window_size += 1
        # Update the maximum submatrix size and its starting indices
        if window_size > max_submatrix_size:
            max_submatrix_size = window_size
            max_submatrix_start_i = i
            max_submatrix_start_j = j
        # Shrink the window size and check again
        for k in range(1, window_size + 1):
            if i + k >= m or j + k >= n or array[i + k, j + k] != 255:
                break
            # Update the maximum submatrix size and its starting indices
            if k + 1 > max_submatrix_size:
                max_submatrix_size = k + 1
                max_submatrix_start_i = i
                max_submatrix_start_j = j
                window_size = k
            break

# Extract the largest submatrix
largest_submatrix = array[max_submatrix_start_i:max_submatrix_start_i + max_submatrix_size,
                          max_submatrix_start_j:max_submatrix_start_j + max_submatrix_size]

print(largest_submatrix)


the output I got is

[[255. 255. 255.   0.   0.   0. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255.   0.   0.   0.   0. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. 255.   0. 255. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. 255.   0. 255. 255. 255.]]



I have tried using sliding window but didn't get much help from it the if any one can solve it. If in case also consider the case where the largest submatrix can have nan values inside it.  If possible can also suggest different approach.

Is there always exactly one column of NaNs to the left and right? If not, give more general example data. It looks like you're just trying to find that longest run of non-NaN rows.

no there is no guarantee that there are actually one column of NaNs the complete 2d matrix is of 1720 rows and 114 columns there is this large area of 255 a group of them in area i want to extract that area. That area can have some times NaNs in the middle of it and the shape of area can be of any zagged size of array.

In that case, please give a more representative example.

Are you OK with a solution that uses an image processing or computer vision library?

What do you mean by odd size? What if the largest submatrix is of 8*12?

Here is a recursive function. You can change it to use while loop in case the matrices are very sparse and the recursion depth is surpassed:
def largest_submatrix(arr):
  """
  Obtain the largest submatrix
  """

  def find_index(arr, idx):
    """
    Obtain the row and col slices containing non-na values
    """
    n,m = arr.shape
    if len(idx) == 2:
      row1, row2 = (idx[0], idx[0] + 1) if idx[0] < n else (idx[0] - 1, idx[0])
      col1, col2 = (idx[1], idx[1] + 1) if idx[1] < m else (idx[1] - 1, idx[1])
      idx = row1, row2, col1,col2,0
    else:  row1, row2, col1, col2,_ = idx
    
    # move up
    if arr[row1-1:row2, col1:col2].all():
      row1 = row1 - 1 if row1> 0 else 0 
    # move down
    if arr[row1:row2+1, col1:col2].all():
      row2 = row2 + 1 if row2 < n else n
    # move left
    if arr[row1:row2, col1-1:col2].all():
      col1 = col1 - 1 if col1> 0 else 0 
    # move right
    if arr[row1:row2, col1:col2+1].all():
      col2 = col2 + 1 if col2 < m else m
    # any movement? if yes, repeat the process above.
    if (np.r_[row1, row2, col1, col2] != idx[:-1]).any():
      return find_index(arr, (row1, row2, col1, col2, 0))
    return row1, row2, col1, col2, (row1 - row2) * (col1 - col2)

  def sub_indices(arr_bool, index, vals = None):
    """
    Compare the slices and obtain the slices with the most values
    """
    row, col = index
    r1, r2, c1, c2, size  = indices = find_index(arr_bool,(row[0], col[0]))
    # slices with max region
    vals = indices if vals is None or size > vals[-1] else vals
    
    # any non-nan value not within the have not been traversed? Repeat
    if (i2 := ~((r1 <= row) & (row <= r2) & (c1 <= col) & (col <= c2))).any():
      return sub_indices(arr_bool, (row[i2], col[i2]), vals)
    return vals
  
  arr_bool = ~np.isnan(arr)
  r1,r2, c1, c2,_= sub_indices(arr_bool, np.where(arr_bool))
  return arr[r1:r2, c1:c2]
          
largest_submatrix(array)
array([[255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255.,   0., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255.,   0.,   0.,   0., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255.,   0., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255.,   0., 255., 255., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.]])


It is still unclear as to what you mean by even submatrix. In case you want even columns/rows, you can simply include that within your code to ensure that the returned values capture as to whether the submatrix is even/odd. Then you can use that to determine the best region:
